# What does the use and meaning of You's in song 'No more "I love you's"'?

Tags: slang, lyrics

I listened this song written by  David Edward & Daniel Freeman. I like that song but I didn't get complete meaning as I don't know the use of "You's" in lyrics. 
Lyrics is as below:

> I used to be lunatic from the gracious days
>       I used to be woebegone and so restless nights
>       My aching heart would bleed for you to see
>       Oh but now
>       (I don't find myself bouncing round whistling
>       and fortunes to make me cry)
>       No more "I love you's"
>       The language is leaving me
>       No more "I love you's"
>       Changes are shifting outside the word
>       (The lover speaks about the monsters)
>       I used to have demons in my room at night
>       Desire,despair,desire,so many monsters
>       Oh but now
>       (I don't find myself bouncing round whistling
>       and fortunes to make me cry)
>
> No more "I love you's"
>       The language is leaving me
>       No more "I love you's"
>       The language is leaving me in silence
>       No more "I love you's"
>       Changes are shifting outside the word

Comment: The transcription is slightly wrong, making it more confusing.  It should be **No more "I love you"s** - that is "No more statements of 'I love you'."

Comment: Ohh..!! I didn't get that side too!! Thanks @stangdon

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The statement in the song is analogous to "no more hellos" where the word  "hello", used in greeting, has become the name for such a greeting. It has become *nominalized*.

> We say our hellos and our goodbyes.

The phrase "I love you" is similarly being turned into a noun that stands for the profession of love, and the noun is being pluralized.

No more *I love yous*.

Comment: Logically, it should be written:

'No more "I love you"s'

But I'm not aware of any style guide that actually says that.

Comment: @Monty I wonder if it wouldn't make more sense to treat it like a compound and write I-love-yous.

Comment: @MontyHarder You're right, because in "I love you's" the apostrophe neither indicates a contraction not is it used suitable to indicticate a possession.

Comment: Logically, Monty is right, but I think the way it is written in the answer (no quotation marks or apostrophe) is the usual style.

Comment: *I love yous* is a nominal, pluralized. How we represent that grammatical status in typography or orthography is a matter of (mere) convention.  Hyphens between the elements is certainly a way to go.

Comment: @DrEval: Apostrophes are often used by native writers to make plurals out of things that don't usually take a plural ending (or which have really weird spellings like [+1](https://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/03/1s-right-recommendations-right-when-you.html)).  The issue here is that we're trying to pluralize a whole phrase, which is not commonly done in English.

Comment: @Kevin Sure (I'm English; here it's called a Grocer's Apostrophe because of its popularity with the purveyors of fresh fruit and vegetables) but it's always wrong to do so.